# Quit docker container that is printing in while loop without stopping it

Tags: docker, containers

I have a docker container constantly printing "Hello world":

`docker container run -d alpine sh -c 'while [ 1 ]; do echo "hello world"; sleep 1; done'`

When I `attach` to the container to view the output, I cannot gracefully quit the container using `ctrl+p ctrl+q`, although this works in other containers. I see `^p` gets inserted to the screen output. I can only `ctrl+c`, but I do not want to stop the container. Increasing the sleep timer does not help either. Is there another way to quit this container without stopping it?